# How to insert values in table with foreign key using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, insert, foreign-keys

I have these two tables just for example:

```
TAB_TEACHER
- id_teacher   // primary key, autoincrement
- name_teacher // a varchar

TAB_STUDENT
- id_student    // primary key, autoincrement
- name_student  // a varchar
- id_teacher_fk // foreign key reference to a teacher (TAB_TEACHER)
```

I want to know how to insert in these two cases:

CASE 1 - INSERT a new Student with an pre-existing TEACHER, so I have to get the foreign key with a teacher name

CASE 2 - INSERT a new Student with a new TEACHER (the teacher I'm creating in the same time I'm creating the student)

Comment: Hey, you need to read a book on basic SQL. Solutions here wouldn't help you in long term. I was about to answer but then thought it's very basic if you are learning SQL. You should crack it yourself. It's simple believe me.

Comment: could you recommend a good one?

Answer (score 31):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

For case1:

```
INSERT INTO TAB_STUDENT(name_student, id_teacher_fk)
SELECT 'Joe The Student', id_teacher
  FROM TAB_TEACHER
 WHERE name_teacher = 'Professor Jack'
 LIMIT 1
```

For case2 you just have to do 2 separate insert statements

Comment: Good, it's very simple just as a normal insert! Isn't there a trick to get the id_teacher_fk "in the insert of the first?"

Comment: This is if you want to add a student with teacher and you only know the names, then it takes the name of student as constant and the id of the teacher from the table

Answer (score 30):

### Case 1: Insert Row and Query Foreign Key

Here is an alternate syntax I use:

```
INSERT INTO tab_student 
   SET name_student = 'Bobby Tables',
       id_teacher_fk = (
       SELECT id_teacher
         FROM tab_teacher
        WHERE name_teacher = 'Dr. Smith')
```

I'm doing this in Excel to import a pivot table to a dimension table and a fact table in SQL so you can import to both `department` and `expenses` tables from the following:

[image]

### Case 2: Insert Row and Then Insert Dependant Row

Luckily, MySQL supports `LAST_INSERT_ID()` exactly for this purpose.

```
INSERT INTO tab_teacher
   SET name_teacher = 'Dr. Smith';
INSERT INTO tab_student 
   SET name_student = 'Bobby Tables',
       id_teacher_fk = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Comment: Is this the most efficient way to do this ??? And what to do if I want to insert multiple values at the same time while inserting ?

Comment: You can add more SET lines to add multiple values.

Answer (score 15):

### Case 1

```
INSERT INTO tab_student (name_student, id_teacher_fk)
    VALUES ('dan red', 
           (SELECT id_teacher FROM tab_teacher WHERE name_teacher ='jason bourne'))
```

*it is advisable to store your values in lowercase to make retrieval easier and less error prone*

## Case 2

[mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
INSERT INTO tab_teacher (name_teacher) 
    VALUES ('tom stills')
INSERT INTO tab_student (name_student, id_teacher_fk)
    VALUES ('rich man', LAST_INSERT_ID())
```

Comment: > it is advisable to store your values in lowercase to make retrieval easier and less error prone

No, you absolutely should not be transforming someone's name willy nilly. Which is why you should use numeric ids that then map to human-readable names.