# Convert UPDATE into INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have this UPDATE MySQL statement which works fine.

```
UPDATE table1 
Inner Join table2 
ON table2.id = table1.gw_id 
SET table1.field1=1, table1.field2=2
WHERE table1.nick_no=4 AND table2.addr=123
```

I would like to convert this UPDATE statement such that it can add a new row if a row with the same `table1_nick_no` is not found. I believe using INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the right way to go. However, I tried for a long time but failed. [Adding Inner join and where clause to INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201283/adding-inner-join-and-where-clause-to-insert-into-on-duplicate-key-update)

How should I convert this UPDATE statement into the corresponding INSERT INTO ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement?

Comment: Edit the query in your question to use table aliases to we can tell where the columns come from.

Comment: Gordon Linoff, I have edited the query to show the tables where the columns belong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a MERGE or an UPSERT (short for UPDATE/INSERT). In mySQL you can achieve an UPSET as described in the following link

http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/09/30/how-to-do-an-upsert-in-mysql/