# MySQL: how to insert into a table with two foreign keys linking to two other tables?

Tags: mysql, database, insert, foreign-keys

I have the following db structure with 3 tables as an example:

Employee

- id          // primary key, autoincrement
- employee_no // a varchar

Scenario

- id            // primary key, autoincrement
- key           // a varchar

Case

- id            // primary key, auto-increment
- employee_id   // foreign key to Employee table
- scenario_id   // foreign key to Scenario table

Say I already have data in employee and scenario table and I want to insert a new case into the case table so that it fills the foreign keys during the insert. The new case has `employee_no` in employee table and `key` in scenario table. I will need to join the two tables using the above values to get employee id and scenario id.

This post ([Mysql: How to insert values in a table which has a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775520/mysql-how-to-insert-values-in-a-table-which-has-a-foreign-key)) showed how this can be done with one foreign key, how do I do the same thing with two foreign keys?

I currently have something like this that does not work:

```
INSERT INTO `case` (scenario_id, employee_id, employee_no)
SELECT 
(SELECT scenario.id FROM scenario WHERE scenario.`key` = 'UC01') as scenario_id,
(SELECT employee.id, employee.employee_no FROM employee WHERE employee.employee_no = "0001") as employee_id, employee_no
```

Comment: What is the problem? Why do you think that having two foreign keys is any different?

Comment: @PM77-1 I don't know how to fit two select query together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the two tables:

```
INSERT INTO case (scenario_id, employee_id)
SELECT s.id, e.id
FROM scenario AS s
CROSS JOIN emplopyee AS e
WHERE s.`key` = 'UC01'
AND e.employee_no = '0001'
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I'm looking for.