# Insert new data into new tables that rely on each other

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I can't figure out how to seed my database with values. Almost every table I have, reference each other, and so I can't figure out how to do my insert statements. Here are my table schemas for the two in question:

```
CREATE TABLE utility_company (
    utility_company_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    utility_company_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    utility_company_monthly_numbers_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (utility_company_id)
);

CREATE TABLE utility_company_monthly_numbers (
    utility_company_monthly_numbers_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    utility_company_id int(11) NOT NULL,
    january_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    february_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    march_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    april_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    may_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    june_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    july_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    august_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    september_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    october_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    novemember_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    december_numbers int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (utility_company_monthly_numbers_id)
);

ALTER TABLE utility_company ADD FOREIGN KEY (utility_company_monthly_numbers_id) REFERENCES utility_company_monthly_numbers(utility_company_monthly_numbers_id);
ALTER TABLE utility_company_monthly_numbers ADD FOREIGN KEY (utility_company_id) REFERENCES utility_company(utility_company_id);
```

I have no values in my database right now, and so I can't figure out how to insert data into even one of these tables, without throwing a foreign key constraint error.
**What can I do here to make my inserts?**

So I've referenced these questions, but I couldn't get my answers:
[Mysql: How to insert values in a table which has a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775520/mysql-how-to-insert-values-in-a-table-which-has-a-foreign-key)

This one didn't work because on the case that makes sense for me, it just said use two insert statements. But no answer on how I can prevent my foreign keys failing

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66778/how-to-insert-data-into-tables-which-reference-each-othermysql

And this one didn't work either because it didn't even really answer the question at all.

Comment: Is it required for a company to always have 1 or more monthly numbers?

Comment: @Tyler yes, because it's for different utility companies, and their rates change month to month

Comment: Hmmm... Why does the utility company need to have a foreign key to the monthly number?

Comment: @Tyler Because I wanted to match companies to numbers...but as I'm typing that, I realize I can probably just put all of those columns in the same table, huh?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should rethink your database design.

If you have `utility_company` and `monthly_number`, it sounds like it should be viable to have 2 tables with 1 foreign key.

`monthly_number` would have 3 columns:

1. foreign key to `utility_company`
2. the `monthly_number`
3. the month (probably an int)

By using this design it goes around your problem with a very simple foreign key structure.

Each record in the table for `monthly_number` would represent the `monthly_number` for a specific company, on a specific month.

If you need to record the numbers across years; then, you can add a `year` column as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would an alternative solution be one that uses a M:N relationship as follows:

```
utility_company: utility_company_id (PK), utility_company_name
month: month_id (PK), month_name
monthly_figures: utility_company_id (composite PK), month_id (composite PK), numbers
```

A `year` column could easily be added to table `monthly figures` as well.

This way, the data in the parent tables must be present before you add anything to the `monthly_figures` *join* table. This solves the *which table do I populate first* issue that you have.

Alternatively, you could use a conventional 1:M scenario where `utility_company_id` is simply an FK on table `monthly_figures`. Here again the parent `utility_company` table would be populated first.