# How to use join in an insert statement mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Let's say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE x (
     id (primary), 
     store_id(foreign, references y (id)),
     item_name, 
     item_quantity, 
     payment_type, 
     date
);
```

And another table

```
CREATE TABLE y (
     id (primary), 
     name, 
     address
);
```

y table is filled with data. I need to insert data into the x table.
The input I have is the y name, so with the name (and the other variables) I should fill an x row. I just don't know how to fill the store_id. I understand what the foreign key does in theory, I have no idea how to apply it in practice.
I need for it to check the name in the y table, then insert the id of the store in the x table. How do I go about doing that? Can I use join in an insert statement? Can I use the WHERE statement, and how?

Comment: Read [`INSERT FROM SELECT ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: you did't put data type of column??

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775520/mysql-how-to-insert-values-in-a-table-which-has-a-foreign-key

Comment: Got it, thanks! Also, I just wrote that create table as an example.

Comment: You need to verify of your insert statement of x table and make sure that all store id should be first available into table y with matching value of id. If not then first insert data for y table and then execute insert query data of x table. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume you have all the data you need to insert on the X table (assuming too multiple insertions, not just one row), except for the **store_id**, but you have instead a name that correspond to the Y table, and this name is unique in the Y table. Then you can do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO X (id, store_id, item_name, item_quantity, payment_type, date)
SELECT
    id,
    (SELECT Y.id FROM Y WHERE Y.name = tbl_values.name) AS store_id,
    item_name,
    item_quantity,
    payment_type,
    date
FROM
    (
        SELECT <id1> AS id, <y_name1> AS name, <item_name1> AS item_name, <item_quantity1> AS item_quantity, <payment_type1> AS payment_type, <date1> AS date
        UNION
        SELECT <id2> AS id, <y_name2> AS name, <item_name2> AS item_name, <item_quantity2> AS item_quantity, <payment_type2> AS payment_type, <date2> AS date
        UNION
        SELECT <id3> AS id, <y_name3> AS name, <item_name3> AS item_name, <item_quantity3> AS item_quantity, <payment_type3> AS payment_type, <date3> AS date

    ) AS tbl_values
```

Comment: This is way more complicated than I think he's asking for. Why do you need all those other columns in the `tbl_values` subquery. I think he just wants to match a single name.

Comment: I'm assuming he needs to insert multiples rows on the X table, not just one row. The table **tbl_values** is just the set of data i'm assuming he have as input. If he needs to insert only one row, then my example can be simplified.

Comment: He wrote **The input I have is the y name** which sound like just one name. But it's not clear where all the other values come from.

Comment: He wrote this: *The input I have is the y name, **so with the name (and the other variables)** I should fill an x row*. I interpret this as he have all the other information too (except for the store_id).

Answer (score -1):

you can insert data for x table normally.

**But when fill store_id column you can only insert data if data will have id column in x table.**

```
INSERT INTO y VALUES ( **'100a'**, 'jimmy', 'german');

INSERT INTO x VALUES ( '12ab', **'100a'**, 'bun', '21','credit card','2018/09/5');
```

Comment: Did you read the question? The problem is how to automatically get `y.id` from `y.name` and put that into `x.store_id`.