# How to insert data into two tabels?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I have two tables `FILM(Id, Title, Director, Year, Category)` and `Record(Id, Film_id)`

`Id` from `FILM` table is used as a foreign key as `Film_id` in `Record` table.

I want to insert data at the same time date into both tables. How construct a sql query with INSERT?

```
using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (var cmdDataBase = connection.CreateCommand())
    {   
        cmdDataBase.CommandText = "INSERT INTO film(Title, Director, Year, Category) VALUES (@Title, @Director, @Year, @Category) ";
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Title", fm.Title));
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Director", fm.Director));
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Year", fm.Year));
        cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Category",n));

        cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what your purpose is. Which two labels? I see only ID and Film_Id in Record table.

Comment: And why hold the same value in two different tables?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli - It seems he wants to fill both tables `film` and `record` at the same time with the foreign key relation. So his question is basically `How to insert a record with foreign relations?` - at least thats how I understand it :)

Comment: Just add a second insert into the Record Table.

Comment: @jdweng but what with the foreign key, so how does he fill the `id` of the table `film` into the related table `record`'s column `film_id`

Comment: As long as the same ID is used for both Inserts everything will work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You get the last auto-generated ID with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. Then, you'd use a transaction, because you don't want to insert a parent record, if you can't also insert the child record, or so I understand.

This is it more or less. You should add error handling (`try`, `catch`) of course.

```
// Start transaction
MySqlTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
command.Transaction = transaction;

// Parent record
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO film(Title, Director, Year, Category) VALUES (@Title, @Director, @Year, @Category) ";
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Title", fm.Title));
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Director", fm.Director));
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Year", fm.Year));
command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@Category",n));
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Child record        
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO record (Film_id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID())";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Commit inserts
transaction.Commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it in sequence. First, add record to your main table Film, then other table Record. Check below:

```
INSERT INTO Film(Title, Director, Year, Category)
VALUES('Title', 'DirectorName', 1990, 'Action');

--Assuming ID for Record table is AUTO_INCREMENT column
INSERT INTO Record(Film_id)
VALUES ((SELECT id FROM Film WHERE Title='Title' and Director='Director'));
```

Also, LAST_INSERT_ID() can be used:

```
INSERT INTO Film
...

INSERT INTO Record
...
film_id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
```

Ref: [Mysql: How to insert values in a table which has a foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775520/mysql-how-to-insert-values-in-a-table-which-has-a-foreign-key)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL try to add `;return LAST_INSERT_ID();` at the end of you query and add return parameter as below.

```cs
var returnVal = cmdDataBase.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal", SqlDbType.Int);
returnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

After `cmdDataBase.ExecuteNonQuery();` extract id from `returnVal`

```cs
var id = returnParameter.Value;
```

After that you can use `id` to perform the second insert.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not `ExecuteScalar();` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery();`?

Comment: @RandRandom: I am not sure, just my preference. There is also tiny nuance. `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row. So I expect we shall user 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' instead of `return LAST_INSERT_ID();`.

Comment: Its been so long since I last actually wrote SQL my self (nonetheless mysql), so I don't really know myself. :) - ORMs drained my SQL knowledge faster than I want to admit. :)