# How to write an SQL multi-insert query for primary and secondary tables

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables and I want to write a multi insert query such that, the PK from first table is auto inserted as fk in another table.

Let us assume following table schemas:

**tblParent**

```
ParentID (Primary Key Auto increment)
ParentValue
```

**tblChild**

```
ChildID (Primary Key Auto increment)
FkParentID (Foreign Key)
ChildValue
```

Now I want to write a multi insert query like following

```
INSERT INTO tblParent, tblChild (ParentValue, FkParentID, ChildValue) VALUES ('Parent 1', <ParentID of 'Parent 1'>, 'Child 1'), ('Parent 2', <ParentID of 'Parent 2'>, 'Child 2'), ('Parent 3', <ParentID of 'Parent 3'>, 'Child 3')
```

But I do not know how to do this.
I have millions of records to be inserted in these tables. And I do not want to insert a record in first table, then fetch parent id and insert records in second table.

Edit 1: My Database is Mysql InnoDb

Edit 2: The tables in question have one-to-many relationship. So this means I want to perform one insert in tblParent and multiple inserts into tblChild for each record in tblParent

Edit 3:

> I was looking in the MySql documentation and came across following description:
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id
>
> The currently executing statement does not affect the value of LAST_INSERT_ID(). Suppose that you generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value with one statement, and then refer to LAST_INSERT_ID() in a multiple-row INSERT statement that inserts rows into a table with its own AUTO_INCREMENT column. The value of LAST_INSERT_ID() will remain stable in the second statement; its value for the second and later rows is not affected by the earlier row insertions. (However, if you mix references to LAST_INSERT_ID() and LAST_INSERT_ID(expr), the effect is undefined.)

So my next question is, how would `LAST_INSERT_ID` behave in case of multi insert for tblParent which in turn has multiple inserts in tblChild for each tblParent

Comment: Similar question and available answer on that post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775520/how-to-insert-values-in-table-with-foreign-key-using-mysql

Comment: @Xun Thanks for the reference. My bad I was not able to search properly. Will look into that question and mark this as duplicate if the answers given there are satisfactory and suits my case.

Comment: @Xun The way my question differs from the referred question is as follows:
I have to perform one-to-many in my child table, whereas the referred question gives answer for one-to-one relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyways, for now what I did is used multi_query to insert values.

I did following inside a while loop:

```
$autoIncForParent = <Max ID from tblParent>;
while(<condition to evaluate>) {
    if (!empty($multiQuery)) {
        $multiQuery .= ";";
    }
    $multiQuery .= "INSERT INTO tblParent (ParentID , ParentValue) VALUES ($autoIncForParent, 'Parent 1');";
    $multiQuery .= "INSERT INTO tblChild (FkParentID , ChildValue) VALUES ($autoIncForParent, 'Child 1');";
$autoIncForParent++;
}
$mysqli->multi_query($multiQuery);
```

I am pretty sure there must be another good way of solving this.

I have taken care of memory issues, race conditions and what nots in my actual code.
This snippet is for elaboration purpose only.
By no means this snippet is perfect and I would not recommend this for production.

Edit 1: Added missing semicolons. In case someone refers this

Comment: I do not recommend this answer for security/stability reasons.  Use prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//your codes

       $inset_tblParent= "INSERT INTO tblParent (ParentValue, FkParentID, ChildValue)VALUES('Parent 1', <ParentID of 'Parent 1'>, 'Child 1')";

     $inset_tblChild= "INSERT INTO tblChild (ParentValue, FkParentID, ChildValue)VALUES('Parent 2', <ParentID of 'Parent 2'>, 'Child 2')";


//your doces            
    ?>
```

you can able to use multiple insert like this.

Comment: In tblParent FkParentID, ChildValue do not exists. How would this work?

Comment: you use  if condition for check

Answer (score 0):

You can Insert data in two table following way:-

```
$result = INSERT INTO tblParent (ParentValue) VALUE('ABC');
if($result == true){
    $query = SELECT * tblParent ORDER BY ParentID DESC LIMIT 1;
    $row = $query->fetch_assoc();
    $ParentID = $row['ParentID'];
    INSERT INTO tblChild (FkParentID,ChildValue) VALUE('$ParentID','XYZ');
}
```

Comment: The problem is I want batch inserts, since I have millions of records to be inserted.
I cannot do individual inserts. It will be very much time taking. And the solution you mentioned is very inefficient for my use-case.

Comment: Which table you have milions of record and which table you want insert data?

Comment: Parent table will have millions or records and child will have (no of records in Parent)*10