# How to insert into table with values from another tables - mysql inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, sql-insert, insert-into

In this case i have created 2 tables:

Projects:

```
CREATE TABLE projects (
ID int(5) NOT NULL,
PROJECT_NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Modules:

```
CREATE TABLE modules (
ID_MODULE int(11) NOT NULL,
NAME varchar(50),
ID_PROJECT int(11) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I've inserted data to projects table:

```
INSERT INTO projects (ID, PROJECT_NAME) VALUES
(1, 'BOX'),
(2, 'Duck')
```

Now I'd like to insert data into "modules" table, but not with ID_PROJECT. I want insert with PROJECT_NAME from "projects" table. When i tried with bellow command:

```
INSERT INTO modules (ID_MODULE, NAME, projects.PROJECT_NAME)
SELECT 1, 'S-BOX', projects.PROJECT_NAME
FROM modules INNER JOIN projects
ON modules.ID_PROJECT = projects.ID AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = 'BOX';
```

It shew an error:

## 1054 - Unknown column 'projects.PROJECT_NAME' in  field list

But when i wrote like this:

```
INSERT INTO modules (ID_MODULE, NAME, ID_PROJECT)
SELECT 1, 'S-BOX', projects.PROJECT_NAME
FROM modules INNER JOIN projects
ON modules.ID_PROJECT = projects.ID AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = 'BOX';
```

It didn't show any error, but it didn't insert any row record to "modules" table.

I have a question is it possible to insert into "modules" table values with inner join another table (inner join "projects" table)? If yes tell what should i do. Thx for any help.

**For example:**

In "modules" table i haven't insert anything. But want insert data:

```
ID_MODULE = 1
NAME = "S-BOX"
projects.PROJECT_NAME = "BOX" (which is inner joined on modules.ID_PROJECT = projects.ID)
```

Comment: Your insert makes no sense, because the three values would always be the same.  Some sample data would really help here.

Comment: 'it possible to insert into "modules" table values with inner join' - Yes it is BUT only if there is an entry in modules to join from. I am not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @P.Salmon I would like to insert values into "modules" table, but with value from "projects" table for example: Instead by `ID_PROJECT` i'd try with `projects.PROJECT_NAME`. For clear I want insert not by `ID_PROJECT = 1`. I'm trying like `projects.PROJECT_NAME = "BOX"`

Comment: And even if there was an entry in modules the query would fail because you are trying to insert a character column(Project_name) to an int(id_project).

Comment: But on the other hand i'm using inner join.

Comment: If a column has a certain data type, it makes little sense for its foreign to have a subtly different data type. In any case (and luckily), the number in parentheses after the INT keyword is almost entirely meaningless and should be omitted.

Comment: A select with any sort of left join(inner or outer) is not going to produce anything if the from table is empty.

Comment: @P.Salmon maybe i forgot add `VALUES`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your first query is incorrect, especially this part `INSERT INTO modules (ID_MODULE, NAME, --> projects.PROJECT_NAME)`. You cannot define another column from another different table than the one that you want to insert into.

2) Your second query is correct. However, if according to your example here, there will be no data inserted since your query do `INNER JOIN` with `modules` table that is empty. You can try an insert without doing `INNER JOIN` like below:

```
INSERT INTO modules (ID_MODULE, NAME, ID_PROJECT)
SELECT 1, 'S-BOX', projects.PROJECT_NAME
FROM projects
WHERE projects.PROJECT_NAME='BOX';
```

I reckon that the query above will work but you will see this message:

```
Warning Code : 1265
Data truncated for column 'ID_PROJECT' at row 1
```

Because if you look at your column datatype for `projects.PROJECT_NAME` it's `varchar(50)` but `modules.ID_PROJECT` it's `int(11)`. Basically, when you look at the inserted data in `modules.ID_PROJECT`, you will see `0` (or maybe `NULL`) instead of the original value from  `projects.PROJECT_NAME = 'BOX'`. Therefore, you need to make sure your column datatype matches to retain the original data.

Comment: I've tested the second query and it has an error:
`#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`project1`.`modules`, CONSTRAINT `modules_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_PROJECT`) REFERENCES `project` (`ID`))` I'm sorry of forgeting add about foreign keys.

Comment: Which query @Prochu1991 ?

Comment: the second which you wrote:

`INSERT INTO modules (ID_MODULE, NAME, ID_PROJECT)
SELECT 1, 'S-BOX', projects.PROJECT_NAME
FROM projects
WHERE projects.PROJECT_NAME='BOX';`

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775520/how-to-insert-values-in-table-with-foreign-key-using-mysql .. see if it can help :)